# Why we don't need to implement Serializable to serialize to xml

Tags: java, xml, serialization

By definition, Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.

But when I used it with XML the object's state was saved into XML without using serializable.

How am I able to do this without `Serializable` interface?

Below is the attached code :

```
public class SerializeXml {public static void main(String[] args) {

Student s1=new Student("Sachin",1);
Student s2=new Student("Abhinav",2);


try {
    XMLEncoder x=new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Students.xml")));
    x.writeObject(s1);
    x.writeObject(s2);
    x.close();
    System.out.println("Success");
}


catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();}}}
```

and here is the Method for storing values

```
public class Student{ public String name;public int rollno;

   public Student(String Name,int Rollno)
   {
        name=Name;
        rollno=Rollno;

   }

   public Student()
   {
        super();
   }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java serialization is a specific byte-format for serializing objects, utilizing `ObjectOutputStream` for serialization and `ObjectInputStream` for deserialization. Objects are 'enabled' for this type serialization by implementing the marker interface `Serializable`.

However you are serializing to XML, which has nothing to do with the normal Java serialization mechanism, so you do not need to implement `Serializable`. Instead you need to follow the 'rules' and expectations of the XML serialization framework you are using.